# How to detect a User vs Script Variable Change in an AngularJS $watch()?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to implement a start and end date on a form, but also allow the user to pick from a bunch of preset date ranges in a drop-down. If the user selects a value from the drop-down, the start and end date fields are populated.  If the user edits one of the fields, the drop-down sets itself to the "custom" selection.

My "naive" implementation is below, but clearly, all of the watches will fire whether or not the fields are changed by the user, or by the controller.  How can I set up my watches so that this might work?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ExportCtrl">
  <select ng-model="dateRange" ng-options="d.name for d in dateRanges"></select>                                    
  <input type="text" ng-model="startDate" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="endDate" />
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
module.controller("ExportCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.dateRanges = [
          { name: 'Custom', startDate: null, endDate: null },
          { name: 'Today', startDate: moment().startOf('day'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Yesterday', startDate: moment().subtract('day', 1).startOf('day'), endDate: moment().subtract('day', 1).endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Last 3 days', startDate: moment().subtract('day', 2).startOf('day'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Last 7 days', startDate: moment().subtract('day', 6).startOf('day'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Last 30 days', startDate: moment().subtract('day', 29).startOf('day'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Month to Date', startDate: moment().startOf('month'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') },
          { name: 'Last month', startDate: moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), endDate: moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month') },
          { name: 'Last 3 months', startDate: moment().subtract('month', 3).startOf('day'), endDate: moment().endOf('day') }
  ];
  $scope.dateRange = $scope.dateRanges[1];

  $scope.$watch('dateRange', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (oldValue === newValue) {
          return;
      }
      $scope.dateRange = newValue;
      $scope.startDate = $scope.dateRange.startDate;
      $scope.endDate = $scope.dateRange.endDate;
  });

  $scope.$watch('startDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (oldValue === newValue)
          return;
      $scope.dateRange = $scope.dateRanges[0];
      $scope.startDate = newValue;
  });

  $scope.$watch('endDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (oldValue === newValue)
          return;
      $scope.dateRange = $scope.dateRanges[0];
      $scope.endDate = newValue;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hope someone has some experience with this! I want to set my $scope value but I don't get the daterangepicker updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your watchers lead to cyclic dependency. You should watch them all at the same time and define your logic in there.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.dateRange + ',' + $scope.startDate.getTime() + ',' + $scope.endDate.getTime(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //recover new values of all three variables from newValue.split(',')
    //if all three values satisfy the constraints defined in $scope.dateRanges, return
    //if dateRange changes, change startDate and endDate
    //if startDate or endDate changes, change dateRange
});
```